# How to explain these Kotlin codes about 'Int' type?

Tags: kotlin

```
var a: Int = 10000
var b: Int = 10000
print(b === a) // Prints 'true'
```

The official doc says: "a === b evaluates to true if and only if a and b point to the same object."

In the codes above, what's "the same object"?

Comment: It probably refers to representation in memory, i.e. pointers to objects have to point to the same address and integers just have to equal (they are not allocated on the heap).

Comment: But how to explain it only on the language level without considering the bottom implementation？

Comment: This has nothing to do with “implementation”.  That's just what referential equality is.  The `===` operator compares the memory of `a` and `b`.  If `a` and `b` are on the stack (as is the case for primitive types) it's the same as `==`.  If `a` and `b` point to some object on the heap the addresses in `a` and `b` are compared.

Comment: Why are perfectly reasonable answers being downvoted? An explanation of downvotes so the authors can improve their answers is preferred, unless the answer is beyond salvage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How is data stored

If you imagine inside the JVM there are 2 types that are stored directly:

- Primitive types [`Int`, `Long`]

  These are stored as the value
- Reference types [`String`, `Object`]

  These are stored as a reference to the object

## How does `===` work

`===` compares the values in memory, so for reference types it checks they refer to the same object, whereas for primitive types it checks that they hold the same value.

## Why are `Int`s primitive objects

Kotlin stores types that can be stored as primitives as primitives as an optimisation, so `Int` is primitive, whereas `Int?` would be stored as a reference type.

Answer (score 2):

**`===`** means we have to check the referential equality between the objects.

```
var a: Int = 10000
var b: Int = 10000
print(b === a)
```

It prints **true** because the reference to `a` and `b` variables are same. It's actually not an object. As the value of `a` and `b` are same that's why their reference is also same. `a` and `b` refers to the same memory allocation as their value is same. `a` and `b` are primitive type variables. So, you will get a warning

> Identity equality for arguments of types Int and Int is deprecated.

```
var c = Integer(10000)
var d = Integer(10000)
print(d === c)
```

It prints **false** because `c` and `d` are two different Integer objects. So, the reference to `c` and `d` are also different.

Comment: May I take it that the official document of this place is not rigorous?

Comment: @Lyn what do you mean by "this place"? If you mean the Kotlin docs, they are quite extensive, though it may not cover all topics equally. The compiler even issues a warning if you try to compare primitives via `===`.

Comment: @Moira - Because the documentation doesn't seem to describe the behaviour of referential equality for "primitives" at all.  You just have to know what Java this is equivalent to in order to understand the behaviour.